# Working with Test Cases using RED Robot Framework Editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, robotframework

I have to work with RED editor based on the requirements below:

1. For executing selected test cases, I have to use *Run Configuration as* option where test cases will be chosen based on the tags specified.

   My question is this: How to provide the tag name against a test case? Referred Sites: https://github.com/nokia/RED/blob/master/red_help/first_steps/create_run.html.md
2. Also: How shall we do parallel testing using RED RF editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RED you can right-click on the test case in the Source Editor and then choose `Run Test:"[test case name]"`. This will then just run the specific test case.

When you want to use the Run Configuration option then make sure that you uncheck those test cases that shouldn't be run.

When you want to prevent certain test cases to be run then tagging is a good way of preventing this. Also the other way around is true; those that you specifically want to have run can be selected. In Robot Script this is done by adding `[Tags]    Tag1    Tag2` to a test case.

The below example has 4 test cases and 3 of them having tags, of those 3 there is 1 with multiple tags.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case No Tags
    Log To Console    ${TEST_NAME}

Test Case Tag1
    [Tags]    Tag1
    Log To Console    ${TEST_NAME}

Test Case Tag2
    [Tags]    Tag2
    Log To Console    ${TEST_NAME}

Test Case Tag1 Tag2
    [Tags]    Tag1    Tag2
    Log To Console    ${TEST_NAME}
```

In RED you can specify which tags should be run in the `Run Configurations` menu item. By ticking the box `Skip tests with these tags` or the reverse `Only run tests with these tags`:

[image]

Then type the tag name in the next input field. The names of the tags in your test suite will then show. Continue typing till the name is complete, or pick one from the list. Hit enter or the plus symbol. This will then result in the below image. Repeat above step for multiple tags.

[image]

Continue to click on the `Run` button to start the test. This will then result in the below console log:

```
Command: C:\Python27\python.exe -m robot.run -e Tag2 
--listener C:\ ... \TestRunnerAgent.py:62945:False 
-s TagProject.Tagging C:\Eclipse\Workspace\TagProject
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0 (Python 2.7.9 on win32)
==============================================================================
TagProject                                                                    
==============================================================================
TagProject.Tagging                                                            
==============================================================================
Test Case No Tags                                                     Test Case No Tags
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test Case Tag1                                                        Test Case Tag1
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TagProject.Tagging                                                    | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
TagProject                                                            | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Eclipse\Workspace\TagProject\output.xml
Log:     C:\Eclipse\Workspace\TagProject\log.html
Report:  C:\Eclipse\Workspace\TagProject\report.html
```

Notice the addition of the `-e Tag2` to the command which the the actual command for filtering with tags. There is more information about filtering in the [Robot Framework documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/). In the [User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html) there is a seperate section on [Tagging](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases)

Comment: Also, To my understanding, Tags can be done only in the Test Case section, but not under keywords even in the resource file. Am i correct?

Comment: Correct. Tagging is only applicable to the test cases and no other level or functionality.